# ORACLE Table insertion

Tags: oracle, insert

I want to insert data into below table, but I got an error. How do I solve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT ("id" VARCHAR(5000 NULL) NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TAB is table of REF TEST_TYP; 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST1_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT 
    ("id" VARCHAR2(500) NULL,
     "extension" "TEST_TAB" NULL )
NOT FINAL;


CREATE TABLE "TEST_OBJ_TABLE" OF "TEST1_TYP"
NESTED TABLE "extension" STORE AS "Allin"
```

Next, I tried to insert data into TEST_OBJ_TABLE like below:

```
insert into "TEST_OBJ_TABLE" ("id","extension")
VALUES(
'0FE71A85',
"TEST_TAB"("TEST_TYP"( '0FE71A8'))
);
```

But I got the below error:

> Error at Command Line : 59 Column : 12
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF SUB_HWOW.TEST_TYP got SUB_HWOW.TEST_TYP
>   00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) Already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364707

Answer (score 1):

As Michael highlighted, you are inserting an object where your declaration asks for a reference to an object. Here is your corrected code, not using a REF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT (id VARCHAR(5000) NULL) NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TAB is table of TEST_TYP; 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST1_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT (
  id VARCHAR2(500) NULL,
  extension TEST_TAB NULL 
)
NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE TABLE TEST_OBJ_TABLE OF TEST1_TYP
  NESTED TABLE extension STORE AS Allin;
```

You can then insert as you want:

```
insert into TEST_OBJ_TABLE (id,extension)
VALUES(
  '0FE71A85',
  TEST_TAB(TEST_TYP( '0FE71A8'))
);
insert into TEST_OBJ_TABLE (id,extension)
VALUES(
  '0FE71A86',
  TEST_TAB(TEST_TYP( '0FE71A8'),TEST_TYP( '0FE71A9'),TEST_TYP( '0FE71AA'))
);
commit;
```

Then when you select, you get this:

```
SQL> select * from TEST_OBJ_TABLE;

ID       EXTENSION(ID)
-------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0FE71A85 TEST_TAB(TEST_TYP('0FE71A8'))
0FE71A86 TEST_TAB(TEST_TYP('0FE71A8'), TEST_TYP('0FE71A9'), TEST_TYP('0FE71AA'))

2 rows selected.
```

From what I see, you want to have a multi-valued type in your table. You do not need object types for that - other than the TABLE type. See this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TAB is table of VARCHAR2(5000); 
/
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  id VARCHAR2(500) NULL, 
  extension TEST_TAB
)   
NESTED TABLE extension STORE AS Allin;
```

Then insert like this:

```
insert into TEST (id,extension)
VALUES(
  '0FE71A85',
  TEST_TAB('0FE71A8')
);
insert into TEST (id,extension)
VALUES(
  '0FE71A86',
  TEST_TAB('0FE71A8','0FE71A9','0FE71AA')
);
commit;
```

And the result is like this:

```
SQL> select * from test;

ID       EXTENSION
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
0FE71A85 TEST_TAB('0FE71A8')
0FE71A86 TEST_TAB('0FE71A8', '0FE71A9', '0FE71AA')

2 rows selected.
```

This is simpler since it eliminates the two intermediate object types.

You could also use a simple VARRAY instead of a NESTED TABLE. That is still simpler, but you need to specify a maximum size of the VARRAY:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TAB is varray(10000) of VARCHAR2(5000); 
/
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  id VARCHAR2(500) NULL, 
  extension TEST_TAB
);
```

Inserts are like above:

```
insert into TEST (id,extension)
VALUES(
  '0FE71A85',
  TEST_TAB('0FE71A8')
);
insert into TEST (id,extension)
VALUES(
  '0FE71A86',
  TEST_TAB('0FE71A8','0FE71A9','0FE71AA')
);
commit;
```

And reading is the same:

```
SQL> select * from test;

ID       EXTENSION
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
0FE71A85 TEST_TAB('0FE71A8')
0FE71A86 TEST_TAB('0FE71A8', '0FE71A9', '0FE71AA')

2 rows selected.
```

The difference is that the VARRAY multi-valued attributes are stored within the main table. They are stored as BLOBs, so when the list is small - less than 4000 bytes, it will be stored inline. Only larger lists will be stored out of line. Nested tables have the advantage of being of any size, but are obviously always stored out of line.

**HOWEVER** The real question is: **why would you want to do this**. While Oracle lets you define multi-valued attributes using a machinery of object types, varrying arrays or nested tables, that is generally not a good approach - except for very specific uses. For instance, Oracle Spatial's SDO_GEOMETRY type uses VARRAYs to store all the points of a geometric shape.

But if your intent is to represent a **one-to-many relationship**, then do yourself a favor and implement it as **two tables**, one for the parents, one for the children and use a foreign key to link the two. This is infinitely much easier to use in applications: much much simpler than dealing with VARRAYs or NESTED TABLES that cannot be used directly in SQL ...

The content of a VARRAY or NESTED TABLE cannot be searched in SQL: you cannot write a SQL select that would return all rows where the VARRAY or NESTED TABLE contains a specific value. To support that you need to define your own operators and define your own domain-specific index type ... Updating one of those constructs in SQL is also not possible: you need to write your own function for doing that.

Furthermore, the database is fundamentally relational: features like query offloading for Exadata or in-memory stores only apply to scalar data types, not objects, VARRAYs or NESTED TABLEs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TEST_TAB` object wants a `REF`erence to an object.  You are attempting to insert an actual object.

In order to use a reference to an object, you need to first record the actual object in another table.